# How to display only the records where there is a match on at least one of several tables?

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have several tables. I'd like to join against. I only want to see records where there is a match on at least one of those tables

```
insert into foo values
  (1),
  (2),
  (3),
  (4),
  (5),
  (6),
  (7),
  (8);

insert into a values
  (1),
  (2),
  (3);

insert into b values
  (3),
  (4),
  (5),
  (6);
```

desired output:

```
id      id      id
1       1       (null)
2       2       (null)
3       3       3
4       (null)  4
5       (null)  5
6       (null)  6
```

Normally I would do this using WHERE EXISTS (eg: below) but that's not supported in SparkSQL. What is the most performant way to achieve this? I would prefer to rely on my join to determine the result rather than filtering the result set. Also, I am not limited to using SparkSQL, dataframe API is great also.

```
select * 
from foo
left join a on foo.id = a.id
left join b on foo.id = b.id
where exists (select 1 from a x where foo.id = x.id)
or exists (select 1 from b x where foo.id = x.id)
;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need `FULL OUTER JOIN` OR `LEFT JOIN` with filter :

```
select f.*, a.*, b.*
from foo f full outer join
     a
     on a.id = f.id full outer join
     b
     b.id = f.id
where a.id is not null or b.id is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `LEFT JOIN` and add some condition in `where`

```
SELECT * 
FROM foo 
LEFT JOIN a on foo.id  = a.id 
LEFT JOIN b on foo.id  = b.id 
WHERE a.id IS NOT NULL OR  b.id IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY foo.id
```

Answer (score 0):

You are close:

```
select * 
from foo left join
     a
     on foo.id = a.id left join
     b
     on foo.id = b.id
where a.id is not null or b.id is not null;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am wondering if it makes more sense for me to use a left semi join. I am concerned that the `is not null` clause is inefficient because we will be bringing back data that will be thrown out.

Comment: @Josh . . . You can try it both ways and see which is faster.

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution with DataFrame API:

```
val foo = (1 to 8).toDF("id")
val a = Seq(1,2,3).toDF("id")
val b = Seq(3,4,5,6).toDF("id")


foo
.join(a,foo("id")===a("id"),"left")
.join(b,foo("id")===b("id"),"left")
.where(a("id").isNotNull or b("id").isNotNull)
.show()

+---+----+----+
| id|  id|  id|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   1|null|
|  2|   2|null|
|  3|   3|   3|
|  4|null|   4|
|  5|null|   5|
|  6|null|   6|
+---+----+----+
```